# Line break through CSS property?

Tags: html, css

In a chain of list elements (`<li>`) with `display: inline`, is there a way to force a line break using a CSS property?

Using a `<br>` within a `<li>` feels dirty, and outside a `<li>` is probably forbidden.

> to clarify:
>
> I need them "display: inline" because I may need to center them within the UL
>
> I need only some of the elements to have a line break.

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing but what is the reason to using display:inline instead of float?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Why do you use display:inline?
2. `display: list-item;` does exactly what you need (which is default for li)

Comment: 1. Because I need to center them in a wide <ul>. 2. Good idea, will try out. 3. Probably true. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can have all `<li>` elements rendered with `float:left` and then set on one of them `clear:left`. This will cause it to "jump" to the next line.

Alternatively, `float:right` and `clear:right` will do a similar thing.

Comment: Won't both work, as the list elements are centered in a 100% wide UL.

Comment: Make UL fixed width and center it. float:left | right will make LIs to be aligned to the left or right, so it may not achieve the needed effect if your UL is 100% wide.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a "line break" after each `<li>` or just after a few certain ones?

For the former: If you set the width wide enough to fill the container, they will line wrap (actually, they only have to be wide enough to fill 51% of their container, since two could no longer fit on one line).  -- but in this case, you probably don't need them to be inline at all.

For the latter: You would probably be better off using `float: left` with a `clear: left` on each one you want to start a new line with.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `display:block;` on the particular `<li>` that you want on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use [the :after pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content) but I haven't played with it much.

Answer (score 0):

```
li.class:after { content: "\a"; white-space: pre; }
```

works for me.